# modification to LCA code for binary tree to check if node is present in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree, least-common-ancestor

I have this code, which calculates `Least common Ancestor` of given two `nodes` in a `Binary tree`.
Currently, it assumes both nodes are present. I can write a helper method just to check if the nodes are present and then call the `LCABT` method. That would require traversing the tree twice. I am wondering if there is a way to check and handle a situation when node is not present with my current code.

```
//LCA of Binary tree
            public static Node LCABT(Node root, int v1, int v2){
                if (root==null)
                    return null;
                if (root.data==v1 || root.data==v2){
                    return root;
                }
                Node left = LCABT(root.left,v1,v2);
                Node right = LCABT(root.right,v1,v2);

                if(left!=null && right!=null)
                    return root;
                else if (left!=null)
                     return left;
                else  if (right!=null)
                       return right;
                return null;
            }
```

Comment: @NiklasB. "instead of O(log n), which would be possible to achieve" - that's only in a balanced binary **search** tree, or if you know where the node is located.

Comment: @Dukeling: Yeah I see that now. I assumed a search tree, but it might not be one. Still the algorithm should not work in the form presented here.

Comment: @NiklasB.: I do not understand what you mean.but the code as it now works. if both are not present, I return null. but if either one is present and other not, I return the one that is present as the Node, which is not correct

Comment: Ignore my stupidity. I'm unable to read code. As for your problem, If `v1 != `v2` and both are present, you will get the situation `if(left!=null && right!=null)` at some point. You can just remember whether this happened or pass it up the call stack during the recursion. If not, at most one of the nodes is present in the tree (assuming there are no duplicates in the tree).

Comment: The problem is if one is present and other is not. for example, I have root.data=5, v1=5 and v2=10 and lets assume v2 is not present. my current code, just return root since root.data=v1, but it did not check if v2 is present..hope I make sense..?

Comment: @Dukeling: O(log n) will work out for balanced tree (it need NOT have to be a search tree I guess). any thoughts on this post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the function return a pair `(state, lca)`.  `state` must be one of:

```
0: Neither v1 nor v2 appear at or under root; lca is meaningless.
1: Only v1 appears at or under root; lca is meaningless.
2: Only v2 appears at or under root; lca is meaningless.
3: Both v1 and v2 appear at or under root, and have LCA equal to lca.
```

The function should begin by checking for base cases:

```
LCABT(Node root, int v1, int v2) {
    if (root == null) then return (0, null);
```

Otherwise, recurse on its left and right children, to see if one of them solves the problem all by itself:

```
    (s1, lca1) = LCABT(root.left, v1, v2);
    (s2, lca2) = LCABT(root.right, v1, v2);
```

and if either `s1` or `s2` is 3, then the LCA has already been found (it's either `lca1` or `lca2`, respectively) and can be returned immediately.  (In fact, you can even obtain a speedup by checking whether `s1 == 3` before making the second call to `LCABT()`: if it is, then we already have the LCA and don't need the second call.)

```
    if (s1 == 3) then return (3, lca1);
    if (s2 == 3) then return (3, lca2);
```

Otherwise, set `s = s1 | s2` (i.e. bitwise OR).  If `s == 3` then we know that `root` is the LCA, but we haven't yet considered *all ways* in which it can be the LCA: it can still be the LCA when only one of `v1` and `v2` is present at or under its children, provided that the other value is at `root` itself:

```
    s = s1 | s2;
    if (root.data == v1) then s = s | 1;
    if (root.data == v2) then s = s | 2;
```

Now all cases in which `root` is the LCA imply `s == 3`, so if `s == 3` then we can return `(3, root)` immediately:

```
    if (s == 3) then return (3, root);
```

Otherwise, at most one of `v1` and `v2` is at or under `root`, so we should return a value indicating which one it is:

```
    return (s, null);
}
```

Finally, the original top-level call to `LCABT()` should obviously regard the function as succeeding only when it returns a `state` value of 3.

Another advantage of this algorithm over yours is that it will not be fooled by duplicate copies of either `v1` or `v2` in the tree.

Comment: I got lost when the bitwise OR operation begins. I am having difficulty following after that.why do you set s = s1 | s2. and I guess the runtime is still O(n)

Comment: Because then s will equal 3 if and only if one of s1 and s2 is 1 and the other is 2.

Comment: A more longwinded way would be: `a = min(s1, s2); b = max(s1, s2); if (a == 1 && b == 2) then s = 3 else s = b;`.  An even more longwinded way would be to write out a complete set of `if` statements, but I'm not gonna do that -- write out the truth table if it's still not clicking.  And yes, the runtime is O(n).

Comment: One more thing that might help: we're treating all `state` values, including `s`, as a 2-bit "bitsets".  Bit 0 (the LSB) = 1 iff v1 appears at or under root, and bit 1 = 1 iff v2 appears at or under root.  Bitwise OR corresponds to taking the union of 2 bitsets.

Comment: I suppose `if (root.data == v1) then s = s | 1;
if (root.data == v2) then s = s | 2;` should be before `(s1, lca1) = LCABT(root.left, v1, v2);
(s2, lca2) = LCABT(root.right, v1, v2);`.

Comment: I am following bits and pieces but cannot see how the entire flow will work, if you would mind giving a sketch of compelete pseudocode..

Comment: I've added some pseudocode lines interspersed between the text description, but honestly I don't know how much that helps -- it's literally just doing exactly what the text is saying.

Comment: Regarding your second-to-last comment ("I suppose..."): no, it doesn't make sense to say `s = s | 1` *before* `s` has been assigned any value -- this statement should appear *after* `s = s1 | s2`, and therefore after the recursive calls.

Comment: I've also added a check for the base case, where `root == null`.